# how to optionally include / delete values in an Active Model Serializer 0.10 class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have the folowing ASM 0.10 :

```
class UserMicroSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :is_friend


  def is_friend
    @instance_options[:is_friend]
  end
end
```

but would also like to support not having the is_friend attribute.

I have tried various things like:

```
class UserMicroSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
  if @instance_options[:is_friend]
    attributes :is_friend
  end


  def is_friend
    @instance_options[:is_friend]
  end
end
```

but get error msg:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

How would I make the @instane_options conditionally include `is_friend`?

Comment: Could you conditionally user another serializer in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can conditionally use a different serializer in the controller then you may be able to do this

```
class SimpleUserMicroSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
end
```

By subclassing the simple serializer, you don't have much code overlap

```
class UserMicroSerializer < SimpleUserMicroSerializer
  attributes :is_friend

  def is_friend
    @instance_options[:is_friend]
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also send { scope: 'is_friend' } from controller and then check it into serializer.

```
class UserMicroSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
 attributes :id, :name, :is_friend

  def filter(keys)
    keys.delete :is_friend if scope and scope[:is_friend]
    super(keys)
  end
end
```